# django mongoengine embbeded document email field

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

I have the following models

```
class Settings(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    call_number = mongoengine.StringField(default='')
    emails = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.EmailField)

class Profile(DocumentBase):
    user = mongoengine.StringField(unique=True)
    set = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(Settings)
```

Then I try do the following

```
 p = Profile(user="root")
 p.save()
 p.set = Settings()
 p.set.emails = ["me@example.com"]
 p.save()
```

And I get the following error

```
TypeError: unbound method _validate() must be called with EmailField instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I made i mistake in the emails field that must be:

```
class Settings(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    call_number = mongoengine.StringField(default='')
    emails = mongoengine.ListField(mongoengine.EmailField())
```